# simplexml into amazon cart

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am having trouble with simplexml and getting an empty array. I'm stuck and so very tired I have trouble formatting the request. Please help if you are able and thank you.:

This is the code that produces it:

```
//complete the request, creating the cart
$formattedResponse = $apaiIO->runOperation($cartCreate);

//print_r($formattedResponse);

//stuff it in a simplexml object
$placeToGo = simplexml_load_string( $formattedResponse );

print_r($placeToGo->xpath('cart/purchaseurl'));
```

and here is the document that I am trying to pull from:

```
And it pulls from this document (dashes added later):
```

`<-?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?->
    <--cartcreateresponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"-->
    <-operationrequest->
    <-httpheaders->
    <-header name="UserAgent" value="ApaiIO [2.0.0-DEV]" /->
    <-/httpheaders->
    <-requestid->1DRADG4SGKV2WEDBCG53<-/requestid->
    <-arguments->
    <-argument name="Service" value="AWSECommerceService" /->
    <-argument name="Item.1.Quantity" value="1" /->
    <-argument name="Item.3.Quantity" value="1" /->
    <-argument name="Operation" value="CartCreate" /->
    <-argument name="Item.5.Quantity" value="1" /->
    <-argument name="Timestamp" value="2015-07-23T14:51:03Z" /->
    <-argument name="Version" value="2011-08-01" /->
    <-argument name="AssociateTag" value="blindworm-20" /->
    <-argument name="Item.4.Quantity" value="1" /->
    <-argument name="Item.1.ASIN" value="1452102988" /->
    <-argument name="Item.4.ASIN" value="B010K4MUBM" /->
    <-argument name="Signature" value="m70A7hXGsGhyes/mMPOSlVktXGaZoO61G3MST94weq8=" /->
    <-argument name="Item.2.ASIN" value="080241270X" /->
    <-argument name="Item.2.Quantity" value="1" /->
    <-argument name="Item.5.ASIN" value="B004XWPYMU" /->
    -/arguments->
    <-requestprocessingtime->0.133409976959229<-/requestprocessingtime->
    <-/operationrequest->
    <-cart->
    <-request->
    <-isvalid->True<-/isvalid->
    <-cartcreaterequest->
    <-items->
    <-item->
    <-asin->1452102988<-/asin->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-/item->
    <-item->
    <-asin->080241270X<-/asin->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-/item->
    <-item->
    <-asin->1937006883<-/asin->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-/item->
    <-item->
    <-asin->B010K4MUBM<-/asin->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-/item->
    <-item->
    <-asin->B004XWPYMU<-/asin->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-/item->
    <-/items->
    <-/cartcreaterequest->
    <-/request->
    <-cartid->183-2974980-0109268<-/cartid->
    <-hmac->g1tm8HiuxH7ymFrqaKF5ILCrcvE=<-/hmac->
    <-urlencodedhmac->g1tm8HiuxH7ymFrqaKF5ILCrcvE%3D<-/urlencodedhmac->
    <-purchaseurl->https://www.amazon.com/gp/cart/aws-merge.html?cart-id=183-2974980-0109268%26associate-id=blindworm-20<-/purchaseurl->
    <-subtotal->
    <-amount->2140<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$21.40<-/formattedprice->
    <-/subtotal->
    <-cartitems->
    <-subtotal->
    <-amount->2140<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$21.40<-/formattedprice->
    <-/subtotal->
    <-cartitem->
    <-cartitemid->C13XEXT5Y4Y8R<-/cartitemid->
    <-asin->1452102988<-/asin->
    <-sellernickname->Amazon.com<-/sellernickname->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-title->Me without You<-/title->
    <-productgroup->Book<-/productgroup->
    <-price->
    <-amount->590<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$5.90<-/formattedprice->
    <-/price->
    <-itemtotal->
    <-amount->590<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$5.90<-/formattedprice->
    <-/itemtotal->
    <-/cartitem->
    <-cartitem->
    <-cartitemid->C3M2X8EJL5FWH3<-/cartitemid->
    <-asin->080241270X<-/asin->
    <-sellernickname->Amazon.com<-/sellernickname->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-title->The 5 Love Languages: The Secret to Love that Lasts<-/title->
    <-productgroup->Book<-/productgroup->
    <-price->
    <-amount->883<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$8.83<-/formattedprice->
    <-/price->
    <-itemtotal->
    <-amount->883<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$8.83<-/formattedprice->
    <-/itemtotal->
    <-/cartitem->
    <-cartitem->
    <-cartitemid->C114ZAXHTN8CHX<-/cartitemid->
    <-asin->1937006883<-/asin->
    <-sellernickname->Amazon.com<-/sellernickname->
    <-quantity->1<-/quantity->
    <-title->How to Love (Mindful Essentials)<-/title->
    <-productgroup->Book<-/productgroup->
    <-price->
    <-amount->667<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$6.67<-/formattedprice->
    <-/price->
    <-itemtotal->
    <-amount->667<-/amount->
    <-currencycode->USD<-/currencycode->
    <-formattedprice->$6.67<-/formattedprice->
    <-/itemtotal->
    <-/cartitem->
    <-/cartitems->
    <-/cart->
    <-/cartcreateresponse->`

Comment: $placeToGo->html->body->cartcreateresponse->cart->purchaseurl; is the full path however produces the error:Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Issue was case-sensitivity. Please close this question.